# facebook app send box problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am having a problem with facebook send box on my app. It is by default like the image bellow.

[image]

I want to view the box like the image bellow.

[image]

can you suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook API does not support it.You have to write custom CSS.